# Forge-Get Item Path along with custom attributes in BIM360 document

Tags: node.js, access-token, autodesk-forge

Two Requirements are needed:

1. Get item path of the document in a BIM360 document management.
2. Get all custom attributes for that item.
   For Req. 1, an api exists to fetch and for getting custom attributes, another api exists and data can be retrived.
   Is there a way to get both the requirements in a single api call instead of using two.
   In case of large number of records, api to retrieve item path is taking more than an hour for fetching 19000+ records and token gets expired though refesh token is used, while custom attribute api processes data in batches of 50, which completes it in 5 minutes only.
   Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch-Get Custom Attributes is for the additional attributes of Document Management specific. While path in project is a general information with Data Management.

The Data Management API provides some endpoints in a format of command, which can ask the backend to process the data for bunch of items.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/ListItems/

This command will retrieve metadata for up to 50 specified items one time. It also supports the flag **includePathInProject**, but the usage is tricky and API document does not indicate it. In the response, it will tell the pathInProject of these items. It may save more time than iteration.

```
 {
     "jsonapi": {
      "version": "1.0"
 },
  "data": {
"type": "commands",
"attributes": {
  "extension": {
    "type": "commands:autodesk.core:ListItems",
    "version": "1.0.0" ,
    "data":{
        "includePathInProject":true
    }

  }
},
"relationships": {
  "resources": {
    "data": [
      {
        "type": "items",
        "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:vkLfPabPTealtEYoXU6m7w"
      },
      {  
        "type": "items",
        "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:bcg7gqZ6RfG4BoipBe3VEQ"
      } 
    ]
  }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Get item path of the document in a BIM360 document management.

Is this question about getting the hiarchy of the item? e.g. rootfolder>>subfolder>>item ?  With the endpoint, by specifying the query param includePathInProject=true, it will return the relative path of the item (pathInProject) in the folder structure.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/

```
"data": {
    "type": "items",
    "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:xxx",
    "attributes": {
        "displayName": "my-issue-att.png",
        "createTime": "2021-03-12T04:51:01.0000000Z",
        "createUserId": "xxx",
        "createUserName": "Xiaodong Liang",
        "lastModifiedTime": "2021-03-12T04:51:02.0000000Z",
        "lastModifiedUserId": "200902260532621",
        "lastModifiedUserName": "Xiaodong Liang",
        "hidden": false,
        "reserved": false,
        "extension": {
            "type": "items:autodesk.bim360:File",
            "version": "1.0",
            "schema": {
                "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/items:autodesk.bim360:File-1.0"
            },
            "data": {
                "sourceFileName": "my-issue-att.png"
            }
        },
        "pathInProject": "/Project Files"
    }
```

or if you may iterate by the data of parent

```
"parent": {
    "data": {
      "type": "folders",
      "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.sdfedf8wef"
    },
    "links": {
      "related": {
        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.project.id.xyz/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:hC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w/parent"
      }
    }
  },
```

- Get all custom attributes for that item. For Req. 1, an api exists to fetch and for getting custom attributes, another api exists and data can be retrived. Is there a way to get both the requirements in a single api call instead of using two. In case of large number of records, api to retrieve item path is taking more than an hour for fetching 19000+ records and token gets expired though refesh token is used, while custom attribute api processes data in batches of 50, which completes it in 5 minutes only. Please suggest.*

Let me try to understand the question better. Firstly, two things: Custom Attributes Definitions, and Custom Attributes Values(with the documents).  Could you clarify what are they with 19000+ records?

If Custom Attributes Definitions, the API to fetch them is
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-custom-attribute-definitions-GET/
It supports to set limit of each call. i.e. the max limit of one call is 200, which means you can fetch 19000+ records by 95 times, while each time calling should be quick (with my experience  < 10 seconds). Totally around 15 minutes, instead of more than 1 hour..
Or at your side, each call with 200 records will take much time?

If Custom Attributes Values, the API to fetch them is
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-versionsbatch-get-POST/
as you know, 50 records each time. And it seems it is pretty quick at your side with 5 minutes only if fetch the values of 19000+ records?

Comment: Thanks Liang for your response. I was able to get the answer to my first requirement, where I am adding 'includePathInProject' as True(which by default is false) as the query string parameter which is giving me completely hierarchy of the item. You are right, i have to call my custom attribute api which finishes in batch of 50 in 5-6 minutes only, but since this custom attribute is not returing me item path, for that i have to call the "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/" one by one , which is consuming time.

Comment: I did missed that query param! My apology! I will update my reply above.  As to get custom attributes, I am checking with engineer team if there is a possibility with the endpoint. Thank you for the reply which helped a lot with your questions.

Comment: a new answer is posted an top. Please check if it helps

Comment: Many Thanks Liang. Please post us if you get any information for fetching the Item path and Item URL in custom attributes API. As it will save an enormous amount of time.